How to validating Resource Settings and Features Against Bicep File
Is there any way to validate all settings and features in the resource and compare them with the Bicep file? I have a Bicep file that needs to be checked and verified against the resource before deployment to ensure it is latest and up-to-date.

Can you share the code tried so far. @Saurabh

what-if can help but not that reliable

Its looks much like there are 2 solutions available to explore here:

Using what-if Command:


using what-if command to preview deployment changes (if you already have a working bicep code for the resources), showing the differences between your defined resources and actual resources.

az deployment group what-if --resource-group <your-resource-group> --template-file <your-template.bicep>


Exporting and Decompiling ARM Templates:


If you starting all from crash and without a bicep code for instance, a case from migrating existing resource not deployed using Infrastructure as a Code (e.g  resources deployed manually from the portal), then might be best exporting the ARM Templates from the existing resources and then converting to bicep, using the decompile command. Once you have this you can do cleanups then check if things are right using what-if command.

az group export --name "your_resource_group_name" > main.json
az bicep decompile --file main.json

